# "Yesod devel" fails with fromJust in devel.hs

Tags: haskell, yesod

When I run "yesod devel" it says "devel.hs: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing

```
yesod init # created a project bbbb
...
cabal install && yesod devel
...
Registering bbbb-0.0.0...
Starting development server...
Starting devel application
devel.hs: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

And the web server is not listening the port (I cannot open the site in my browser)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

My environment:

- yesod-0.9.4.1
- The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.0.3
- Mac OS X 10.6.8

Here is dist/devel.hs, which "yesod init" created:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}
import "bbbb" Application (withDevelAppPort)
import Data.Dynamic (fromDynamic)
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
    (runSettings, defaultSettings, settingsPort, settingsHost)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)
import System.Directory (doesFileExist, removeFile)
import System.Exit (exitSuccess)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Starting devel application"
  wdap <- (return . fromJust . fromDynamic) withDevelAppPort
  forkIO . wdap $ \(port, app) -> runSettings defaultSettings
    { settingsPort = port
    , settingsHost = "0.0.0.0"
    } app
  loop

loop :: IO ()
loop = do
  threadDelay 100000
  e <- doesFileExist "dist/devel-terminate"
  if e then terminateDevel else loop

terminateDevel :: IO ()
terminateDevel = exitSuccess
```

I uploaded all files in bbbb directory and Application.hs is
https://github.com/suztomo/LanguageStudy/blob/master/Haskell/Yesod/bbbb/Application.hs .

Comment: Can you include the contents of `devel.hs`? It sounds like a bug in Yesod to me.

Comment: Thanks, I added dist/devel.hs.

Comment: `withDevelAppPort` is *supposed* to look like (Substitute "Webapp" for your foundation data type): `withDevelAppPort = toDyn $ defaultDevelAppWith loader withWebapp; where loader = loadConfig (configSettings Development) { csParseExtra = parseExtra }`

Comment: This is a mismatch between the type expected by the `dist/devel.hs` file, and either your version of `yesod-default` or `Application.hs`. This is far more convoluted than it should be. Thanks to this question, the issue will be fixed in Yesod 0.10.

Comment: Michael,
Thank you for the comment, but it looks like I'm using yesod-default 0.5...

Comment: dflemstr, Thank you for the comment, but I'm still having problem: "`csParseExtra' is not a (visible) constructor field name"

Comment: It looks like the discrepancy between Yesod.Config.AppConfig and Yesod.Default.Config.AppConfig is causing the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure about Data.Dynamic but withDevelAppPort is lacking the  second parameter for defaultDevelApp ...?
https://github.com/suztomo/LanguageStudy/blob/master/Haskell/Yesod/bbbb/Application.hs

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark answer: check in your cabal file that you're using yesod-default 0.5.

Comment: I'm using yesod-default...

    , yesod-default                 >= 0.5        && < 0.6

Comment: Ahhh... one other idea: do you have WAI 1.0 installed? This can introduce different versions of the `Application` type.

Comment: I tried to use wai 1.0 but the yesod-default-0.5 requires wai 0.4.*.
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-default-0.5.0 

How can I solve this...?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear: that's the source of the problem. Try unregistering wai 1.0, it's causing trouble.

Comment: After I registered wai-1.0.0, it worked! Thank you very much.