# When I type yesod devel I get the error: file devel.hs not found

Tags: yesod, haskell-platform

When I type yesod devel I get the following error:

> ERROR: file devel.hs not found

How do I fix this?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, my ghc version is 7.4.1 and my yesod version is 0.10.2.1

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974146/yesod-devel-fails-with-fromjust-in-devel-hs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have not setup the Yesod scaffolding yet. Run 'yesod init' first, then cd into the created directory and try 'yesod devel'.

Comment: For Latest Yesod versions: The "init" command has been removed. Please use 'stack new' instead. May be you need to recreate the project folder.

Answer (score 2):

Use stack to create and build the project. Please use 'stack new'  to create a new project and initialize again.

Comment: this should be the the answer, also ensure, that you use the latest stack and yesod, tutorial [here](https://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart).